# Django Document upload issue does not show "no file selected"

Tags: django

I have the following form:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

This produces a form which produces (in [] brackets denotes a button):

```
**Document:**
[Choose File] no file selected
[Upload]
```

When I use the following form:

```
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.document }}
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
```

I don't get the "no file selected" part in Safari but I do in chrome.  Is there some sort of "form.something" that will allow me to have it shown in whatever browser.

Form is as follows:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('document', )
```

Model is as follows:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    document = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

HTML Output for the manual example (in chrome):

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='2ZMTQTumTh5DS4nwVvAZv3IUSpM2o5LB' />
        <input id="id_document" name="document" type="file" />
        Document

        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

[image]

HTML Output for the manual example (in safari):

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='DTLKigyikubFrJqrh4AHR61Lmkyutrsw' />
        <input id="id_document" name="document" type="file" />
        Document

        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

[image]

HTML Output for the automatic example (in safari):

Document:

Upload

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: What is `form.document`?

Comment: Added my form and model which should explain.  Many thanks for information.

Comment: how does the rendered html look like?

Comment: add the different html outputs, hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the result in chrome and safari? And what version of safari do you use?

Comment: Safari Version: Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7), images adding very shortly.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with django. I'd rather dig into css (maybe width/color/overflow is overridden for input elements).

Comment: Make sense :)  Will go have a play, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you included (request.FILES) in your views.py file if not add like this .

```
def view(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():

       #Then Save your Form
```

Comment: It was included but may not be for someone else so will accept the answer.  Interestingly my fix was a good old reboot!